# Why child component does not see changes?

Tags: angular

Here's an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GN8YNJqBkTRhnGFKkDfs?p=preview) with 2 arrays. I've tried to do the same with two-way data binding via @Input and @Output. Child component:

```
public handleEvent(isSelected:any){
  this.user = isSelected;
}
public isSelected(user) {
    console.log(this.selected);
    return this.selected.indexOf(user) !== -1;
}
@Output('childData') outgoingData = new EventEmitter<string>();
public sendData(data:any){
    this.outgoingData.emit(data);
}
@Output() event: EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();
clickOnUser(user) {
    if (this.selected.indexOf(this.user) !== -1) {
        this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(this.user), 1);
    } else {
        this.selected.push(user);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
p([ngClass]="{ 'selected': 'isSelected(user)' }" (event)="clickOnUser()", , (ngModelChange)="sendData($event)") {{user.Name}}
```

Parent component:

```
sampleChildData;
public handleEvent(childData:any){
    this.sampleChildData = childData;
}
```

Unfortunately nothing works: all items in a list are red, ie they are all selected. How should it be done?

Comment: I don't get what the question is. The Plunker seems to work fine.

Comment: There should be two components. Parent component should pass its arrays to a child component.

Comment: Binding to ngModelChange is not working in this case, because it get's triggered by changes of the value property of the element it is attached to. You can simply add the call to `sendData` to `clickOnUser`.